# Is this const_cast undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, const-cast

I was wondering whether the following is undefined behavior

```
// Case 1:
int *p = 0;
int const *q = *const_cast<int const* const*>(&p);

// Case 2: (I think this is the same)
int *p = 0;
int const *const *pp = &p;
int const *q = *pp;
```

Is this undefined behavior by reading a `int*` as if it were a `int const*`? I think it is undefined behavior, but I previously thought that only adding `const` in general is safe, so I'm unsure.

Comment: You are asking us! :-) As a matter of interest, do you have a real world use case for this? And like you, I've always assumed that adding constness can't break anything.

Comment: @unapersson ah I just read the last c++0x spec and it turns out it has the answer! I was discussing this problem with my colleague today, who added "const" to a "T" for "T*" as an interator adapter and ran into a problem that begged for this implicit conversion.

Comment: I think this is totally fine and I don't see anything dangerous here.

Comment: Do you mean to imply that passing e.g. a `double*` to a function taking a `double const*` would cause UB? I'd be amazed if this were true

Comment: @ildjarn: a related issue is whether passing a converted `double **` into a function taking a `double const**` is UB (when that function uses it), but the example you give is not a consequence of this being UB. If this even is UB, I mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Qualification-wise, it's fine. With each expression split into a statement:

```
int *p = 0; // ok
int **addrp = &p; // ok
int const *const *caddrq = addrp; // ok, qualification conv. according to §4.4/4
int const *q = *caddrq; // ok
```

Note that the rules of `const_cast` (§5.2.11/3) are identical to those of qualification conversion, but without the requirement of being monotonically increasing in qualification. In your case, because you're only ever adding qualifications the `const_cast` is unnecessary.

---

Concerning aliasing, I don't think it's an issue, here, or at least it's not intended to be.

Like you mentioned, there's a new bullet in the C++0x list of allowed access methods (§3.10) that allows similar types ("similar" being types arising from qualification conversions). In C++03 that bullet is missing, but I suspect that the bullet about allowing more cv-qualified access was meant to cover that, but it technically isn't so (that is, the commitee overlooked this).

Comment: @GMan i mean, if I read the "int*" by an lvalue of type "int const*" is this not an aliasing violation? When I looked into the spec today, I seem to have missed that they added a new bullet for C++0x to the aliasing rule list!

Comment: @GMan "int const*" is not a more cv-qualified version of "int*". "int * const" would be.

Comment: @Johannes: Oh, yes, I get it now and I see that too. That's interesting, because I think the intent of the bullet I now mention in my answer was to cover the newly added bullet, but there must have been an overlook (or I'm just expecting to much from it). Do you know why that is?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! For the formalities: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#158