# Undefined behaviour with const_cast

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, const-cast

I was hoping that someone could clarify exactly what is meant by undefined behaviour in C++. Given the following class definition:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    explicit Foo(int Value): m_Int(Value) { }
    void SetValue(int Value) { m_Int = Value; }

private:
    Foo(const Foo& rhs);
    const Foo& operator=(const Foo& rhs);

private:
    int m_Int;
};
```

If I've understood correctly the two const_casts to both a reference and a pointer in the following code will remove the const-ness of the original object of type Foo, but any attempts made to modify this object through either the pointer or the reference will result in undefined behaviour.

```
int main()
{
    const Foo MyConstFoo(0);
    Foo& rFoo = const_cast<Foo&>(MyConstFoo);
    Foo* pFoo = const_cast<Foo*>(&MyConstFoo);

    //MyConstFoo.SetValue(1);   //Error as MyConstFoo is const
    rFoo.SetValue(2);           //Undefined behaviour
    pFoo->SetValue(3);          //Undefined behaviour

    return 0;
}
```

What is puzzling me is why this appears to work and will modify the original const object but doesn't even prompt me with a warning to notify me that this behaviour is undefined. I know that const_casts are, broadly speaking, frowned upon, but I can imagine a case where lack of awareness that C-style cast can result in a const_cast being made could occur without being noticed, for example:

```
Foo& rAnotherFoo = (Foo&)MyConstFoo;
Foo* pAnotherFoo = (Foo*)&MyConstFoo;

rAnotherFoo->SetValue(4);
pAnotherFoo->SetValue(5);
```

In what circumstances might this behaviour cause a fatal runtime error? Is there some compiler setting that I can set to warn me of this (potentially) dangerous behaviour?

NB: I use MSVC2008.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is this const_cast undefined behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969867/is-this-const-cast-undefined-behavior)

Comment: If you're using a C-style cast, any decent compiler should warn you that you're "discarding qualifiers". Do make sure to always enable all warnings.

Comment: "doesn't even prompt me with a warning to notify me that this behaviour is undefined" - revise your expectations down. C and C++ compilers are capable of noticing only a tiny proportion of things that cause undefined behavior. Using `const_cast` or a C-style cast at all means, "I know that what I'm doing is dangerous, don't stop me". The general philosophy of C++ compilers and programmers is that a warning here would not be useful, since the presence of a `const_cast` in the code is warning enough.

Comment: Btw, there's a valid (if annoying and rare) way to use this, which is if you were passing a reference to `MyConstFoo` into some code that in fact doesn't modify it (and is documented not to do so, etc), but wasn't written with const-safety in mind and hence takes a `Foo&` instead of a `const Foo&`. The fact that casts of pointers/references are dangerous, and used for dangerous things, and hence require extra scrutiny, is one reason to work to avoid using them. Still, sometimes some third-party library, especially old C interfaces taking a non-const pointer, will ruin your day.

Comment: @Kerrek: Really? [I've _never_ seen that](http://www.ideone.com/bdRSQ). You're more likely to see "discarding qualifiers" when [you're _trying_ to discard qualifiers in a manner that's ill-formed](http://www.ideone.com/uC7Xn).

Comment: Increase the optimization level see if it still works :-)

Comment: See also: [c++ - Is const_cast safe? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357600/is-const-cast-safe) and the question linked in the comment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I was hoping that someone could clarify exactly what is meant by undefined behaviour in C++.

Technically, "Undefined Behaviour" means that the language defines no semantics for doing such a thing.

In practice, this usually means "**don't do it**; it can break when your compiler performs optimisations, or for other reasons".

> What is puzzling me is **why this appears to work and will modify the original const object** but doesn't even prompt me with a warning to notify me that this behaviour is undefined.

In this specific example, attempting to modify any non-mutable object may "appear to work", or it may overwrite memory that doesn't belong to the program or that belongs to [part of] some other object, because the non-mutable object might have been optimised away at compile-time, or it may exist in some read-only data segment in memory.

The factors that may lead to these things happening are simply too complex to list. Consider the case of dereferencing an uninitialised pointer (also UB): the "object" you're then working with will have some arbitrary memory address that depends on whatever value happened to be in memory at the pointer's location; that "value" is potentially dependent on previous program invocations, previous work in the same program, storage of user-provided input etc. It's simply not feasible to try to rationalise the possible outcomes of invoking Undefined Behaviour so, again, we usually don't bother and instead just say "**don't do it**".

> What is puzzling me is why this appears to work and will modify the original const object **but doesn't even prompt me with a warning to notify me that this behaviour is undefined.**

As a further complication, compilers are not *required* to diagnose (emit warnings/errors) for Undefined Behaviour, because code that invokes Undefined Behaviour is not the same as code that is ill-formed (i.e. explicitly illegal). In many cases, it's not tractible for the compiler to even detect UB, so this is an area where it is the programmer's responsibility to write the code properly.

The type system — including the existence and semantics of the `const` keyword — presents basic protection against writing code that will break; a C++ programmer should always remain aware that subverting this system — e.g. by hacking away `const`ness — is done at your own risk, and is generally A Bad Idea.™

> I can imagine a case where lack of awareness that C-style cast can result in a `const_cast` being made could occur without being noticed.

Absolutely. With warning levels set high enough, a sane compiler *may* choose to warn you about this, but it doesn't have to and it may not. In general, this is a good reason why C-style casts are frowned upon, but they are still supported for backwards compatibility with C. It's just one of those unfortunate things.

Answer (score 5):

Undefined behaviour **depends on the way the object was born**, you can see [Stephan](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-/Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-Cpp-8-of-n) explaining it at around 00:10:00 but essentially, follow the code below:

```
void f(int const &arg)
{
    int &danger( const_cast<int&>(arg); 
    danger = 23; // When is this UB?
}
```

Now there are two cases for calling `f`

```
int K(1);
f(k); // OK
const int AK(1); 
f(AK); // triggers undefined behaviour
```

To sum up, `K` was born a non const, so the cast is ok when calling f, whereas `AK` was born a `const` so ... UB it is.

Comment: This seems to follow C semantics detailed at [Is it Undefined Behaviour to cast away the constness of a function parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9079104/608639) Does it hold for C++ too? It would be nice to see the C++ standard cited.

Answer (score 4):

Undefined behaviour literally means just that: behaviour which is not defined by the language standard. It typically occurs in situations where the code is doing something wrong, but the error can't be detected by the compiler. The only way to catch the error would be to introduce a run-time test - which would hurt performance. So instead, the language specification tells you that you mustn't do certain things and, if you do, then anything could happen.

In the case of writing to a constant object, using `const_cast` to subvert the compile-time checks, there are three likely scenarios:

- it is treated just like a non-constant object, and writing to it modifies it;
- it is placed in write-protected memory, and writing to it causes a protection fault;
- it is replaced (during optimisation) by constant values embedded in the compiled code, so after writing to it, it will still have its initial value.

In your test, you ended up in the first scenario - the object was (almost certainly) created on the stack, which is not write protected. You may find that you get the second scenario if  the object is static, and the third if you enable more optimisation.

In general, the compiler can't diagnose this error - there is no way to tell (except in very simple examples like yours) whether the target of a reference or pointer is constant or not. It's up to you to make sure that you only use `const_cast` when you can guarantee that it's safe - either when the object isn't constant, or when you're not actually going to modify it anyway.

Answer (score 4):

> What is puzzling me is why this appears to work

That is what undefined behavior means.
It can do anything including appear to work.
If you increase your optimization level to its top value it will probably stop working.

> but doesn't even prompt me with a warning to notify me that this behaviour is undefined.

At the point it were it does the modification the object is **not** const. In the general case it can not tell that the object was originally a const, therefore it is not possible to warn you. Even if it was each statement is evaluated on its own without reference to the others (when looking at that kind of warning generation).

Secondly by using cast you are telling the compiler **"I know what I am doing override all your safety features and just do it"**.

For example the following works just fine: (or will seem too (in the nasal deamon type of way))

```
float aFloat;

int& anIntRef = (int&)aFloat;  // I know what I am doing ignore the fact that this is sensable
int* anIntPtr = (int*)&aFloat;

anIntRef  = 12;
*anIntPtr = 13;
```

> I know that const_casts are, broadly speaking, frowned upon

That is the wrong way to look at them. They are a way of documenting in the code that you are doing something strange that needs to be validated by smart people (as the compiler will obey the cast without question). The reason you need a smart person to validate is that it can lead to undefined behavior, but the good thing you have now explicitly documented this in your code (and people will definitely look closely at what you have done).

> but I can imagine a case where lack of awareness that C-style cast can result in a const_cast being made could occur without being noticed, for example:

In C++ there is no need to use a C style cast.
In the worst case the C-Style cast can be replaced by reinterpret_cast<> but when porting code you want to see if you could have used static_cast<>. The point of the C++ casts is to **make them stand out** so you can see them and at a glance spot the difference between the dangerous casts the benign casts.

Answer (score 2):

A classic example would be trying to modify a const string literal, which may exist in a protected data segment.

Comment: How about an object that starts its life as non-const as detailed by @Nikos?

Answer (score 0):

Compilers may place const data in read only parts of memory for optimization reasons and attempt to modify this data will result in UB.

Answer (score 0):

Static and const data are often stored in another part of you program than local variables. For const variables, these areas are often in read-only mode to enforce the constness of the variables. Attempting to write in a read-only memory results in an "undefined behavior" because the reaction depends on your operating system. "Undefined beheavior" means that the language doesn't specify how this case is to be handled.

If you want a more detailed explanation about memory, I suggest you read [this](http://www.ualberta.ca/CNS/RESEARCH/LinuxClusters/mem.html#mmap). It's an explanation based on UNIX but similar mecanism are used on all OS.