# can I return non-cost pointer from 'const type *var' parameter after pointer casting/arithmetic?

Tags: c, pointers, constants

I'm writing own `frame` for some communication and I wrote some functions to calculate position of 'tail' section. As frame size depend on incoming `frame->head->size` then it is not possible to write single struct for all field containing `crc` and 'end', so i wrote some helper functions to return pointer to 'frame_tail_t' etc.
Now I'm wonder is it correct to use `const frame_t *frame` as parameter where it return non-const pointer that might be modified?
Compiler do not complain about that but I feel there is something wrong.
Or is there any method which allow me for write something similar to 'pseudo_frame_t'?

for example

```
frame_tail_t *tail = frame_tail(frame);
tail->crc16 = 0x1234;
```

code:

```
frame_tail_t * frame_tail(const frame_t *frame){
    uint32_t tailOffset = frame_size(frame)-FRAME_SIZEOF_TAIL;
    return (frame_tail_t*)&frame->byte[tailOffset];
}

FRAME_SIZE_T frame_size(const frame_t *frame){
    return frame_head(frame)->size;
}

frame_head_t * frame_head(const frame_t *frame){
    uint32_t headOffset = 0;
    return (frame_head_t*)&frame->byte[headOffset];
}

struct pseudo_frame_t // just for overview
{
    uint8_t start;
    uint8_t size;
    uint8_t type;
    uint8_t cnt;
    
    uint8_t data[dynamicSize];
    
    uint16_t crc16;
    uint8_t end;
};

typedef struct frame_t frame_t;
struct frame_t
{
    uint8_t byte[1];
    // frame_head_t head;
    // uint8_t data[dynamic]
    // frame_tail_t tail;
};

typedef struct frame_head_t frame_head_t;
struct __attribute__((__packed__)) frame_head_t
{
    uint8_t start;
    FRAME_SIZE_T size;
    uint8_t type;
    uint8_t cnt;
};

typedef struct frame_tail_t frame_tail_t;
struct __attribute__((__packed__)) frame_tail_t
{
    #ifdef FRAME_OPT_CRC
    FRAME_CRC_T crc16;
    #endif
    uint8_t end;
};
```

Comment: The `const` is only in the scope of the related function. When the function returns a pointer it can be modified any way unless you don't define the returned `frame_tail` as constant like `const frame_tail_t *tail = frame_tail(frame);` In your case it can't be modified within the `frame_tail` function scope, but it can when the function returns. You can validate it by checking the crc's value after assigning it.

Comment: @Kozmotronik in other words, it is fine as long as I do not perform any write operation related to const pointer inside function scope event after casting etc?

Comment: yes, even you attempt to modify that const parameter in the function, the compiler will not permit this.

Comment: @Kozmotronik im aware of that I can not direclty write to 'frame' but after casting it do not show any warning. frame_tail_t * frame_tail(const frame_t *frame){
    uint32_t tailOffset = frame_size(frame)-FRAME_SIZEOF_TAIL;
    frame->byte[0] = 123; // its obviously illegal
    frame_tail_t *tail = (frame_tail_t*)&frame->byte[tailOffset];
    tail->crc16 = 0x1234; // compiler do not complain
    return (frame_tail_t*)&frame->byte[tailOffset];
}

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9079161/3150445

Comment: Compiles != correct.  Runs without crashing != correct. Avoid undefined behavior (UB).

Comment: Well but actually the modified object is not the member of frame itself directly. You modify the `crc` which is member of `frame_tail` which is member of `frame`. The `frame` is constant but its member is not. So the compiler is happy, so are you. I mean it is ok to do that.

Comment: @Kozmotronik `frame_tail` is not member of `frame` explicitly, its offset from `frame` and casted to `frame_tail`, they both occupied same memory regoin but they can not be determined by single struct/union AFAIK as it depend on `frame->byte[1]` value which is `head->size`

Comment: @Dobijasek this will not change anything about this matter since you define a new non-constant handle (pointer) for it.