# Overloading subscription operator() or [] with no code repetition

Tags: c++, optimization, operators, operator-overloading

I have two versions of operator():

```
const A& operator(int x ,int y) const;
A& operator(int x ,int y);
```

But I don't know what would be the best way to avoid code repetition (because they essentially have the same logic).

I did read the awesome FAQ regarding operator overloading (and some other questions) but did not find answer.

**EDIT_1:** I've tried the suggestion that Skizz proposed but something like that does not quite work for me but maybe I've missed something:

Because [this](http://pastebin.com/VT8J52f7) works while [this](http://pastebin.com/Ks8P9udt) does not compile giving the following error:

error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘int&’ from expression of type ‘const value_type {aka const int}’

Comment: If the logic is the same, making one of them call the other should do the trick, no?

Comment: How do you do that without `const_cast`?

Comment: What are the implementations of these functions?  If they are identical (as can be implied by your statement), then you could simply write 1 of them and ignore the other.

Comment: @ZacHowland I need the ability to both edit information and access it in other const methods.

Answer (score 2):

If both methods 'essentially have the same logic' then surely they should both be marked const. If they do behave differently, should they be called the same thing?

What you need is a third, hidden method that does the common thing, like this:-

```
const A& operator(int x ,int y) const
{
  return Common (x,y);
}
A& operator(int x ,int y)
{
  return Common (x,y);
}
A& Common (int x, int y) const
{
   // common code
}
```

This takes advantage of the implicit non-const to const conversion. In the first method, the this object remains const in the call to Common but the non-const return value is converted to const. In the second, the non-const this object is converted to a const this object and the return object is unchanged.

Comment: They are the same in the sense that they both go and find an item at x,y coordinates but sometimes I'd like it to be a constant ref and sometimes not...

Comment: const matters here because the operators return references. One should be able to modify a(x,y)=5 if and only if a is non-const; one should be able to access z=a(x,y) regardless of whether a is const or not.

Comment: @Michael: In the original question, it's not clear if the operators are members of A or if A is a separate class. In the latter case, the constness of the operator function does not affect the constness or the return value. In the former case, yes, you'd need const and non-const operators.

Comment: @Skizz I've tried doing what you proposed but it doesn't work, maybe I've missed something ? (I've edited the question with more info)

Comment: @SadStudent: You're returning a reference to a member so it has the same constness as the constness of the this pointer (the first of the two alternatives I mention in my previous comment).

Answer (score 1):

If you have the data in question as shared/unique pointer, you are able to forward it to a common function:

```
class X {
    public: 
    const A& operator () (int x ,int y) const { 
        common(data, x, y);
        return *data;
    }

    A& operator () (int x ,int y) { 
        common(data, x, y);
        return *data;
    }

    private:
    void common(std::shared_ptr<T>, int x ,int y) const;
    std::shared_ptr<A> data;
};
```

Now you are able to access the T* via data.get() which is 'T* get() const'.
(Note: I consider the common function a bad design)

You might do, also:

```
class X {
    public:
    const A& operator () (int x ,int y) const { 
        common(x, y); 
        return data;
    }

    A& operator () (int x ,int y) { 
       // ... make mutations
       common(x, y); 
       // ... make mutations
       return data;
    }

    void common(std::shared_ptr<T>, int x ,int y) const;
    T data;
};
```

Or actually, making the data mutable, if it is not breaking logical const:

```
class X {     
    const A& operator () (int x ,int y) const { 
        // ... make mutations on the mutable data, only
        return *lazy_evaluated_data;
    }

    A& operator () (int x ,int y) { 
        const X& self = *this;
        self(x, y);
        return *lazy_evaluated_data;;
    }

    private:
    mutable T lazy_evaluated_data; // or a cache
};
```

Comment: Doesn't the second operator make a `const A&` i.e a const reference into a non const reference ?

Comment: @SadStudent No, but the shared poinnter has the function 'T* get() const'

Comment: OK but it's a plain vector anyway so I guess it's not relevant :\ And what would you consider a good solution for this problem? I can think of some bad ones too :)

Comment: Don't make data mutable for coding convenience. This may cause unintended data modifications from other seemingly const functions.

Comment: @Michael I know - it may be a cache

Answer (score 0):

Write a helper function and call it from both operators. You'll need to do some `const_cast<...>(this)` which can be ugly, but it's a common pattern.

Comment: Doing `const_cast<...>(this)` is more than ugly - [it could lead to undefined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7349559/335858).

Comment: @cdmh as the previous commenter said I tend to avoid const_cast in a similar way I avoid fire :) so if there's some work around that would not use const_cast it'd be nice

Comment: @SadStudent that's generally good advice, but nothing is so bad that it should be avoided without good reason. See duplicate answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123758/how-do-i-remove-code-duplication-between-similar-const-and-non-const-member-func which references Scott Meyers' solution using `const_cast` AND `static_cast` together ;)