# Why does this variable need to be static?

Tags: c++, arrays, static, member

```
class armon
{
    static const int maxSize=10;    

    int array[maxSize];

    int count=0;

    int* topOfStack=array;
}
```

Why does `maxSize` need to be `static` for it to be used inside array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two aspects to this question

Aspect 1

C++ array is of fixed size, the size of which needs to be known during compile time. If the decision needs to be deferred during runtime, the array expression becomes ill-formed.

Aspect 2

Declaring a member variable as non-static makes it an  instance variable, the value of which only exist once the object is instantiated which is done during run-time. A static variable is a class variable, the value of which can be determined during compile time.

Your particular example becomes the classic chicken-egg paradox.

```
class armon
{
    static const int maxSize=10;    

    int array[maxSize];

}
```

- In order to instantiate your class `armon`, you need to know its size.
- In order to know its size, you need to know the size of individual members. In your particular case, you need to know the size of the array.
- In order to know the size of the array, you need to know the value of the dependent variable maxSize.
- In order to  access the dependent variable maxSize you need to instantiate the class  `armon`.
- In order to instantiate your class `armon`, you need to know its size.

So, your array size dependent variable should be a constant expression, which in your particular case should be a static variable,

Answer (score 12):

It doesn't **have** to be static, but it must be a **constant expression**.

C++ Standard § 8.3.4 [dcl.array] (emphasis mine) :

> If the constant-expression (5.19) is present, it shall be a converted **constant expression of type std::size_t** and its value shall be greater than zero

---

That is, the following is also valid :

```
constexpr std::size_t Size()  { return 10; }; 

struct Y
{
    int array[Size()];
};
```

---

**Note:**

Since the compiler needs to know the size of the class, you cannot do this :

```
struct Y
{
    const int size = 10;
    int array[size];
};
```

Possibly making different instances of `Y` having different sizes.

Also note that in this context, `int array[size]` is **not** a constant expression, because it makes use of `this`, see the C++ standard section § 5.19 [expr.const] :

> A conditional-expression e is a core constant expression unless the evaluation of e, following the rules of the abstract machine (1.9), would evaluate one of the following expressions:
>
> — **this** (5.1.1), except in a constexpr function or a constexpr constructor that is being evaluated as part of e;

(the evaluation of `size` is really `this->size`)

Comment: this is due to the fact that the compiler is able to reserve memory during compilation. A good explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21350478/what-does-memory-allocated-at-compile-time-really-mean)

Comment: You also need to explain why `const int maxSize = 10;` is not considered to give a constant expression, but `static const int maxSize = 10` is

Comment: @MattMcNabb sure, note added

Comment: Next question, given that there is not actually a `Y() : size(5) {}` why shouldn't `size` be a constant expression in that case?

Comment: @MattMcNabb see my second edit, it is **not** a constant expression ( § 5.19 )

Comment: @quantdev I mean, why doesn't the standard say that `const int size = 10;`, where it is not overruled by a constructor init list, is a constant expression. I guess there was no demand for such a feature.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have to be static, it has to be constant.

When you declare a constant inside a class you will be making a constant **for each** instance of the class.

Also if your `maxSize` is just `const` you would have to intialize it in the constructor initializer list because `const maxSize` is treated as variable whose value you can't change.

Inside a class `const`
keyword means "This is a constant during the hole lifetime of this object". **Different objects of the same class can have different values for that constant.**

But when it is a static constant there will be **only one constant** for all instances of the class. This means that you have to initialize constants value on the same line where you are defining it.

Comment: "if your maxSize is just const you would have to intialize it in the constructor initializer list " is wrong! It can also be a scoped variable that has not to be initialized in initializer list.
"Inside a class const keyword means "This is a constant during the hole lifetime of this object"" is also wrong. It is just a "hint" to the programmer. Think about `const_cast<>`

Comment: @lifeOfPI: It's more than a hint. You can't cast away the const_ness and use the object in a non-const way. That would be Undefined Behavior, and may break in quite unexpected ways. One _expected_ way in which it breaks is that the compiler may have created multiple copies of a constant, and you'd change only one.

Comment: You do not have to initialize it in the constructor initializer list, e.g. `int count = 0;` in OP's code.

Comment: @ MSalters: IMO you are partially right, [it is 1 of 3 scenarios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349559/undefined-behaviour-with-const-cast). So `const` is no guarantee that it will never be changed.

Comment: `lifeOfPi` a const object may not be modified by your code, end of story.